# How to add static library in STM32CubeMX Makefile? Windows

Tags: c, makefile, static-libraries, stm32

I have a Makefile generated by STM32CubeMX for a project. I have a precompiled static library file lib1.a inside the following folder.

```
Project Dir/
 Core/
  Lib/
   lib1.a header1.h header2.h
```

I have been trying to add this static library file but it says

> cannot find -llib1

How do i add this library to my Makefile? I am using VS Code on Windows 10 for compiling Makefile using GNU ARM and OpenOCD.

```
######################################
# target
######################################
TARGET = APComV2


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source

######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Core/Src/main.c \
Core/Src/gpio.c \
Core/Src/usart.c \
Core/Src/stm32l4xx_it.c \
Core/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_msp.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l4xx_hal_exti.c \
Core/Src/system_stm32l4xx.c

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32l433xx.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via 
GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S

#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m4

# fpu
FPU = -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16

# float-abi
FLOAT-ABI = -mfloat-abi=hard

# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32L433xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-ICore/Inc \
-ICore/Lib/ \
-IDrivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32L4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32L4xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections - 
ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections - 
ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32L433RCTxP_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys -llib1
LIBDIR = -LCore/Lib/
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,- 
Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex 
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o 
$@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
$(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
$(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
$(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
$(HEX) $< $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
$(BIN) $< $@    

$(BUILD_DIR):
mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
-rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)

#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)

# *** EOF ***
```

EDIT: I have added the complete Makefile above. The line i added in this files are:

> -ICore/Lib \

> -llib1 -LCore/Lib/

I am making using following command.

> make -j4 all

All the sources compiles perfectly fine but, when linking the library it gives following output

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc build/main.o build/gpio.o build/usart.o 
build/stm32l4xx_it.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_msp.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_tim.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_tim_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_uart.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_uart_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_gpio.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_dma.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_dma_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o build/stm32l4xx_hal_cortex.o 
build/stm32l4xx_hal_exti.o build/system_stm32l4xx.o 
build/startup_stm32l433xx.o -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 - 
mfloat-abi=hard -specs=nano.specs -TSTM32L433RCTxP_FLASH.ld -LCore/Lib/ -lc - 
lm -lnosys -llib1 -Wl,-Map=build/APComV2.map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections -o 
build/APComV2.elf

c:/program files (x86)/gnu arm embedded toolchain/9 2020-q2- 
update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.3.1/../../../../arm-none- 
eabi/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llib1

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [build/APComV2.elf] Error 1

The terminal process 
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command make -j4 
all" terminated with exit code: 1.
```

Please point out my mistake and help me with this linker problem.

Comment: Just to let others know. I have found a temporary solution for now by adding the sources inside Makefile for compilation which i do want to include in any release. But still waiting if someone could help me with this.

Comment: I'm a make noob but why -LCore/Lib what's that -L doing? shouldn't it be just the path?

Comment: -L is for directory reference to find the .a files. I don't know what i am doing wrong i m creating a project clone on linux to find out....

Comment: There is no way to tell what the problem is because you haven't told us which target is failing to build, and you haven't shown us either the make rule that builds the target nor the command line that make printed when it ran the linker.  So, we can't guess what the issue is.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: a helpful tool here is sysinternals procmon, you can see exactly what file paths the linker is trying to read

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is, your library name. Your lib‘s name is lib1 and you have always to ignore the lib prefix, so -l1 is incorrect.

Example:

```
Library’s name should start with lib
Name: libmystaticlib.a
Linker Option: -lmystaticlib
Path Opion: -L/path/to/lib
```